# VBA search for repeating single character using a Regex

Tags: regex, vba, excel

So I've been learning VBA this past week and I have coded a database cleaning tool. However I am trying to Implement a clean that removes any signs of a repeating character. Specifically xxx, TTTTT, 6666 etc. However searching online and doing some research I couldn't find a solution.

I figured the regex would look similar to something like this:
"^[(\w)+]$"

But that will just find any word characters and replace them so I need to set the search to find any one character, repeated over and over.

I saw someone had "^(.)\1+$" which Seemed to do the trick, however it cut off the ends of my data I didn't want to search for.

I'm shocked that there hasn't been any topics on this, and I figured a regex would be easiest way to find it instead of doing a hard code, eg. looping through the cell value and checking each char.

Thanks it's been wracking my brain all day.

Comment: Instead of being "shocked", try to find what you haven't well understand.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about how the site runs.  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41771756/edit) to add what *output* you want for, e.g., `xxx`.  Please also add the key portions of the code you have so far so people can understand the context of your question more easily.  Thanks!

Comment: The syntax for backreferences in `RegExp` is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhdcs5c(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. I changed your regex to `(.)\1+` so it can remove repeating characters everywhere. Don't forget to add Regexp with Tools > Reference > Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

```
Public Function cleanRange(cells As range)
    Dim pattern As String: pattern = "(.)\1+"
    Dim subst As String: subst = "$1"
    Dim regex As New RegExp

    Dim cell As range
    For Each cell In cells
        With regex
            .Global = True
            .pattern = pattern
            If .Test(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Value = .Replace(cell.Value, subst)
            End If
        End With
    Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: Your pattern should be "(.)\1+", not "(.)$1+"

Comment: I suggest you set the `.global` and `.pattern` properties outside of the loop.  No need to be resetting them for each cell.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais Thanks, It didn't quite work the way I needed it too. It was to check plate numbers and have it clean the cell if someone entered xxxxx in just to fill it, sometimes plates have multiple repeating characters eg. Cattle. The regex would clean the two tt's to just one. I did a loop for cleaning it.

Answer (score 0):

I coded it like this and that worked the way I needed it to.

```
For pp = 1 To Len(Sheets(1).Cells(x, "I").Value)
                    char1 = Mid(Sheets(1).Cells(x, "I").Value, pp, 1)
                    If pp < Len(Sheets(1).Cells(x, "I").Value) Then
                        char2 = Mid(Sheets(1).Cells(x, "I").Value, pp + 1, 1)
                        If char1 <> char2 Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Else
                        Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
                        delFlag = 1
                       Exit For
                    End If
                Next
```